# Is it possible that utmz, utma cookie would not be set for certain users?

Tags: google-analytics

We use google analytics for tracking on our website. Does utmz, utma cookie set for every user?

How correct would it be to consider all those users without utmz, utma as crawlers/bot?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Google Analytics does not use utm cookies at all. So users without utm cookies are not considered bots (unless they are recognized as bots by some other means).

In previous versions the utm cookie where used to store campaign information on the client side. The current version does not store any information in the browser except a clientID, campaign attribution etc. is done on the Google servers.

Currently used by Google Universal Analytics are the _ga cookie for the client id, a throttling cookie to implement the hits per minute-limit for the javascript tracking code and a very short-lived cookie that is used in enhanced link attribution.

**Edited in answer to the comment**

If the _ga cookie was not set the Javascript tracking code would try to generate a new client id and set the cookie accordingly. On success it would register a new visitor. On failure tracking would be aborted and the visit would not be tracked at all.

Bots are not recognised by cookies, or lack thereof. To the best of my knowlegde Google uses the [IAB/ABC International Spiders and Bots List](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/iab-abc-international-spiders-bots-list/) to detected bots (plus undoubtly some proprietary algorithm).

Comment: so can we use _ga cookie, if is UA, _ga is not set, how good it would be to consider them as bot?

Comment: Updated the answer in response to the comment.

Comment: "On failure tracking would be aborted and the visit would not be tracked at all." how often such failure could happen for genuine users/clients? Any idea?